# Using createButton in opencv2.4.5 (Qt gui features) segfault

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am actually having trouble with the following OpenCV sample:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.5/modules/highgui/doc/qt_new_functions.html

(I updated path for my env & added the callbacks functions that are not in the sample).

I compiled Opencv setting Qt On:

```
 GUI: 
--     QT 4.x:                      YES (ver 4.8.2 EDITION = OpenSource)
--     QT OpenGL support:           NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
```

When I try the code I found in Qt doc: I have the following backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff14f53e8 in QAction::setEnabled(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4
#1  0x00007ffff67bf0db in GuiReceiver::enablePropertiesButtonEachWindow() () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#2  0x00007ffff67c02db in GuiReceiver::addButton(QString, int, int, void*, void*) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#3  0x00007ffff67c5e9a in GuiReceiver::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#4  0x00007ffff0fcef77 in QMetaMethod::invoke(QObject*, Qt::ConnectionType, QGenericReturnArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#5  0x00007ffff0fd134c in QMetaObject::invokeMethod(QObject*, char const*, Qt::ConnectionType, QGenericReturnArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument, QGenericArgument)
    () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#6  0x00007ffff67b23a7 in cvCreateButton () from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4
#7  0x0000000000400f6c in main (argc=, argv=) at main.cpp:20
```

Does Anyone has the same issue ?
I just want to precise that I don't want to embed Opencv in Qt but just use Qt features provided by opencv.

I found a start of answer here: 
[How to use cv::createButton prototype in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084511/how-to-use-cvcreatebutton-prototype-in-opencv)

But this was not relevant...

Thanks for your help.

Still having some problems there is a piece of code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void callbackButton(int state, void* userdata){}

int main(int ac, char **av){

     namedWindow("main1",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
     namedWindow("main2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_GUI_NORMAL);
     int a = 0;

     createButton("test",callbackButton, &a, CV_CHECKBOX,1);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I **cannot confirm nor deny** that this problem is real since I have a different setup on my machine (OpenCV 2.4.9 and Qt 5.0.2).

But I found that creating a window with `CV_GUI_NORMAL` crashes the application. The docs states:

> **CV_GUI_NORMAL** or **CV_GUI_EXPANDED**: CV_GUI_NORMAL is the old way to draw the window without statusbar and toolbar, whereas CV_GUI_EXPANDED is the new enhance GUI.

I suggest you create your windows with `CV_GUI_EXPANDED` for the time being.

Comment: I already tryed CV_GUI_EXPANDED with no effect... Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I also could not create a button with OpenCV 2.4.5 / Qt 4.8.0. I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.9 and installed it under the same settings, and now it works.